# What are "primaries" in find?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, find

I was reading the manual for the `find` command. As I was going down the list of options I was reading the following..

> PRIMARIES
>
> ```
>  All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded
>  by a plus sign (``+'') or a minus sign (``-'').  A preceding plus
>  sign means ``more than n'', a preceding minus sign means ``less than n''
>  and neither means ``exactly n''.
> ```

I was having a hard time understanding what that means. I was also trying to find out what are "Primaries" in Google and couldn't get a good answer.

Can anyone help me understand what this means?

Comment: Looks like OSX `find`? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html Added the tag for completeness.

Comment: Reading the top of the manual, it is clear that `primaries` are the options and `operands` are the arguments

Comment: There's a `PRIMARIES` section heading in the manual, and it's followed by a list of all the primaries: `-Bmin`, `-Bnewer`, etc.

Comment: @Jidder Ohh okay, I see now. But what is the [-H | -L | -P] show next to the find command stand for?

Comment: @json2020 It literally says what they are directly below ? Also i realised saying arguments in the previous comment was the wrong word, the operands are things for joining together the options.

Comment: Those are options, they're described below `The options are as follows`

Comment: @Barmar I Know that the options are described below. But my question is why are only those specific options shown next to find command?

Comment: Because they're mutually exclusive, so they're grouped into a single OR block.

Comment: @Barmar So pretty much you can't use them all at once like -hlp   ??

Comment: You can't use `-HLP` together. Read the descriptions of them, you'll see that it doesn't make sense to use them together, because they specify different ways to process symbolic links.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. That's actually what I did and realized the same thing... you can't use them all together. I have one more question In the following sypnosis below Why is the -f path surrounded in brackets at the first line and the second line its not surrounded in brackets??

`find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]`

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command accepts two kinds of parameters, they have been named 'primaries' and 'operators' by the authors of `find`.  Primaries are parameters that allow filtering which files you want `find` to find, while Operators are the parameters that allow combining the primaries.

In mathematics, a primary is the basic component in an arithmetic or logic expression.

There also is a third class of parameters, that have no name and that modify the directory hierarchy traversal behavior of `find`, and a forth class that define what action to take upon the found files (print, delete, etc.)

The GNU man page uses the word 'Test' instead of 'Primary'

Answer (score 1):

From the man page, this is the list of primaries in OS X find:

```
 -Bmin
 -Bnewer
 -Btime
 -amin
 -anewer
 -atime
 -cmin
 -cnewer
 -ctime
 -d
 -delete
 -depth
 -empty
 -exec
 -execdir
 -flags
 -fstype
 -gid
 -group
 -ignore
 -ilname
 -iname
 -inum
 -ipath
 -iregex
 -iwholename
 -links
 -lname
 -ls
 -maxdepth
 -mindepth
 -mmin
 -mnewer
 -mount
 -mtime
 -name
 -newer
 -newerXY
 -nogroup
 -noignore_readdir_race
 -noleaf
 -nouser
 -ok
 -okdir
 -path
 -perm
 -print
 -print0
 -prune
 -regex
 -samefile
 -size
 -type
 -uid
 -user
 -wholename
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to Linux and I am trying to get a good feel of how it works. Does the listed primaries work on any command or just the find command?

Comment: Every command has its own options. These are all specific to `find`.

Comment: FWIW you are not using Linux if you are on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

From the beginning of the same man page (emphasis mine):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The find utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path listed, evaluating an expression (composed
>        of the **``primaries''** and ``operands'' listed below) in terms of each file in the tree.

"Primary" is the term used by the `find` documentation for one of the building blocks of an expression used by `find` to filter its output.